# How many trapezoids (none of them are parallelograms) can be formed from these points?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In the figure shown  below,  we have $2$ rows of points  (first row has $7$ points,  and the second row has $9$ points).  The points are one unit length apart, and the rows are $2$ units length apart.

Question:  How many trapezoids (none of them are parallelograms) can be formed from these points? 
[image]

My try

To avoid making parallelograms, we have to choose  $(n+1) , (n+2), \ldots, 9C9$  points from the second row for each case of  $n$ points  from the first row, For instance , $(n>1)$
$$7C2×(9C3+9C4+9C5....+9C9)+ 7C3 (9C4+9C5....+9C9)+
7C4 (9C5....+9C9)+7C5 (9C6...+9C9)+7C6×(9C7+9C8+9C9)
7C7×(9C8+9C9)$$

These are my thoughts about the problem.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried (please describe your thought process in detail), and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Remove the exclamation mark before the image link to show the link.

Comment: Actually I prefer it with the exclamation point before the link, so we see the image together with the text of the question. I can always right-click if I really want the URL of the image itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straight forward solution is to use inclusion-exclusion. Obviously it's quite easy to count the number of trapezoids totally (ie $\binom72\binom92$. Then you should exclude all rectangles, left leaning and right leaning parallellograms.

Rectangles can be formed by selecting two points of the upper row (and the points in the lower are given). This means $\binom72$ possibilities.

Right leaning rectangles are formed by selecting the lower left corner, the upper left and upper right. These will be uniquely determined by their column and all different. This means $\binom83$ possibilities (because you don't get to select from the rightmost column as there's no points in the upper row there).

This means $\binom72\binom92 - \binom72-2\binom83$

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you are looking at the problem methodically.
You can make things simpler for yourself, however,
and avoid some mistakes.

First of all, consider what you mean by "$n$ points from the first row."
Actually, it was a bit unclear what you meant by this, but let's look at the case $n=3.$
If you mean to choose *any* three points on the top row,
for example the $1$st, $2$nd, and $4$th points,
notice that by connecting these three points you trace the same line segment as you would get from the $1$st, $2$nd, $3$rd, and $4$th points,
which is one of the sets you will get for $n=4.$
So if you mean to choose the points that way you are overcounting the number of cases.

On the other hand, if you meant that the chosen set of points will consist of all the points that are on that edge of the trapezoid,
then the points must all be consecutive.
But $7\mathrm C3$ is the number of ways to choose three points,
*not necessarily consecutive,* from the seven points in the top row.
In fact there are a lot of ways to choose three non-consecutive points.
So if this is what you mean, again you are overcounting the number of cases.

But you have also undercounted, because you have not considered trapezoids in which the top edge is longer than the bottom edge.

Here is a hint:
when you are choosing a set of consecutive points,
you only need to known the leftmost endpoint and the rightmost endpoint of the segment. If you just choose those two points, you then know $n$ (how many of the indicated points are on that segment) and you know exactly *which* $n$ points the segment contains.

If the question were just how many trapezoids, without requiring them not to be parallelograms, it would be relatively easy to say how many there are using just the two endpoints of the top edge and the two endpoints of the bottom edge.
But to exclude parallelograms while you count trapezoids could get complicated.
To keep things relatively easy, I think it pays to solve the easier problem first (how many trapezoids, including parallelograms),
and then count the number of parallelograms and remove them from your initial count of trapezoids,
as recommended in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

First count ALL the quadrilaterals you can make by choosing two of the top points and two of the bottom points.  That's $${7\choose2}{9\choose2}=756$$

Now count, for each possible width, the parallelograms (including rectangles) that can be made this way.  This is trickier, but starting with "skinny" ones it's
$$\sum_{j=1}^{7}(7-i)(9-i)=$$
$$6\times8+5\times7+4\times6+3\times5+2\times4+1\times3=$$
$$48+35+24+15+8+3=133$$

The exact answer, thus, is $$756-133=623$$